# How to choose URLs for pages in RESTful app

Tags: rest

I think I understand a bit about REST architecture. But how do I choose an URL for a web page where resource is represented. Say, I have a list of users and in order to get all users I query an url **/users** with **GET** request. 
But what url to choose for a web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter what URL structure you choose. You should add links to your responses and use the link relation from the client to navigate. You should read more about [REST constraints](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), before you start anything.

There are a few rules about URLs

- a single resource can have multiple URLs, but a single URL can identify only a single resource
- the path should contain the hierarchical and the query should contain the non-hierarchical part of the URL
- you map URLs to resources, so if they are human readable then they probably consist of nouns and not verbs
- URLs can identify any type of resources, not just web documents, but abstract concepts, or things from the real world (by non web document resources you have to use 303 redirect or fragment identifier)

So for example you can have a web document which contains a list of users. That web document can have for example the following URLs: `/users` or `/customers` or if you want to add pagination, then probably `/users?offset=0&count=25` or `/customers/page:1`, etc... You build human readable URLs to make routing on server side easier and probably to check whether you really map your URLs to resources and not to operations. As you can see these URLs does not contain verbs. I could use `/RetrieveUserList/FromPage:1`, but that would be RPC URL mapping (because the `retrieve`). By REST you use standard HTTP methods to manipulate the resources identified by the URLs. There are only a few of these methods, but in most cases they are enough if you combine them with the proper nouns.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with /users/page for a web page since I have /users for users resource.

Comment: Probably "homepage" would be a better word.

Answer (score 1):

The url you've just described is perfect for a web page if the web page displays a list of all users. If you use a framework like spring MVC to implement it you would be able to direct the output to a jsp which would include that list in generating a web page.

Comment: Its best not to use users for the webpage, He should use a different page that makes a request to users however.

Comment: Yes, it is becoming popular to have single page apps that call services like app/users from ajax to populate an area on the page. There are many websites that use REST directly like this: http://acorn.tv/franchise/jeeveswooster  which returns a page of all the Jeeves and wooster episodes. So it is also a perfectly valid way to use rest.